# Does Pentaho Data Integration has Excel 2007 (.xlsx) ouput in a transformation?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Does Pentaho Data Integration has Excel 2007 (.xlsx) ouput in a transformation?
I'm using PDI 4.1.0 Stable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Microsoft Excel Writer** Step. It can generate xls file in xls or xlsx extension

Comment: seems like Microsoft Excel Writer Step is only available in Kettle 4.2 onwards, so I downloaded the plugin from [here](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/kettle-plugins/excel-writer-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a step that does this then no. But you can do csv which Excel can easily read.

Comment: thanks Gordon, but really need the output in xlsx format :)  Is that possible to add a plugin that has this Excel 2007 output step?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate excel 2007 output then use the below hops

1)Microsoft Excel Writer Step. It can generate xls file in xls or xlsx extension

2)Microsoft Excel Output Step. It Can generate XLS or XLSX ext